# obtaining values of a map made within a fetch

Tags: javascript, dictionary, fetch

I am creating a function that fetch an array of users, which are objects, from a server, once the promises are resolved, I make another fetch to access the transport data of each user, which are also objects. When I have all the data, I must gather the data of each object through a map, finally the goal is to create a table where the user data and transport data that corresponds to each user appear.
The problem is that, when I try to access the attributes that I have added to the objects, they come out undefined in the table, whereas if I look at the console the array with the objects has all the attributes correctly. Could someone explain to me what is due?

Here I leave the code of the function where the fetches are made:

```
function users() {
    var arrayPromises;
    fetch('http://.users.php').then(response => response.json()).then(function (users) {
        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            fetch('http://transport.php', {
                method: 'post',
                body: "idtransport=" + users[i].transport,
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
            })
                .then(function (promise) {
                    return promise.json()i
                }).then(function (promiseTransport) {
                arrayPromises += users.map(function () {
                    return users[i].idTransport = promisesTransport.id, users[i].nameTransport = promisesTransport.name, users[i].url = promisesTransport.url;
                });
            });
        }
        allTable(users);
        console.log(users)
    })
}
```

And here I leave the function that shows the table on screen:

```
function allTable(users) {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length + 1; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            if (i === 0 && j === 0) {
                var textCell = document.createTextNode("User");
                cell.appendChild(textCell);
            } else if ( i === 0 && j === 1){
                var textCell = document.createTextNode("Surname");
                cell.appendChild(textCell);
            } else if ( i === 0 && j === 2){
                var textCell = document.createTextNode("Second Surname");
                cell.appendChild(textCell);
            } else if ( i === 0 && j === 3){
                var textCell = document.createTextNode("Age");
                cell.appendChild(textCell);
            } else if ( i === 0 && j === 4){
                var textCell = document.createTextNode("Transport");
                cell.appendChild(textCell);
            } else if ( i === 0 && j === 5){
                var textCell = document.createTextNode("Image");
                cell.appendChild(textCell);
            } else if (i > 0 && j === 0) {
                var textCell = document.createTextNode(users[i-1].name);
                cell.appendChild(textCell);
            } else if (i > 0 && j === 1) {
                var textCell = document.createTextNode(users[i-1].surname);
                cell.appendChild(textCell);
            } else if (i > 0 && j === 2) {
                var textCell = document.createTextNode(users[i-1].surname2);
                cell.appendChild(textCell);
            } else if (i > 0 && j === 3) {
                var textCell = document.createTextNode(users[i-1].age);
                celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
            } else if (i > 0 && j === 4) {
                var textCell = document.createTextNode(users[i-1].nameTransport);
                cell.appendChild(textCell);
            } else if (i > 0 && j === 5) {
                var textCell = document.createElement("img");
                textCell.src = users[i-1].url;
                cell.appendChild(textCell);
            }
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    tabla.appendChild(tblBody);
    body.appendChild(tabla);
    tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

Here I leave an image of the table and the console.log, so you can see that in the console, each of the objects in the array do have the added attributes, but effectively when show them on the screen they come out as undefined (I have translated the names of variables and attributes in the code, but in the image they still come out in the original language).
[image]

Comment: What is `hilera`?

Comment: hilera is row i forgot the translate

Comment: What does `arrayPromises` used for?

Comment: for save every value returned in the map that is inside of for loop

Comment: So unrelated to the solution, but, `arrayPromises` is initialized as `undefined`, `+=[]` is still `undefined.`

Comment: So how can i save the returned value?

Comment: Well as from the code above, I see that `arrayPromises` is not used, I would just remove it. I see that you are using `Array.map()` which changes the entire array. I'll edit my answer with my suggestion, it's a bit too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: thx a lot @StevenTang you are awsome!

Comment: Why did you add a dot at the beginning of your question title? I've now removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Promise.all(array)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in array resolve.

When we create the multiple fetch requests to "transport.php", we push the promise chain into the array `promises`. We await for `Promise.all(promises)` to resolve then call `allTable(users)

It it likely that `console.log(users)` points to a live reference of the data, so when you view it, the promises have already resolved, but when `allTable(users)` is called the promises have not been resolved yet.

```
function users() {
  // var arrayPromises;
  var promises = [];

  fetch('http://.users.php').then(response => response.json()).then(function(users) {
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      promises.push(fetch('http://transport.php', {
          method: 'post',
          body: "idtransport=" + users[i].transport,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          }
        })
        .then(function(promise) {
          return promise.json()
        })
        .then(function(promiseTransport) {
          // arrayPromises += users.map(function() {
          //   return users[i].idTransport = promisesTransport.id, users[i].nameTransport = promisesTransport.name, users[i].url = promisesTransport.url;
          // });
          // this is equivalent to the above, except it does not have an unecesary map.
          users[i].idTransport = promisesTransport.id;
          users[i].nameTransport = promisesTransport.name;
          users[i].url = promisesTransport.url;
        })
      );
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
      allTable(users);
      console.log(users);
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: What your old code `arrayPromises += users.map(...` was doing was mapping `users[i].url` to `users`, which is then added to `undefined`.